# Don't get any response by Instagram API

Tags: php, api, instagram

Here is my code :

```
<?php

  function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
  }
  $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=majoe_47&access_token=[hidden]");
  var_dump($result);
  $result = json_decode($result);
  foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    // Do something with this data.

  }
?>
```

output: `bool(false)`

output on direct url :

> `{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"username":"majoe_47","bio":"Breiter als der T\u00fcrsteher","website":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/majoeduisburg","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10584773_1460870534165160_603268483_a.jpg","full_name":"Majoe","id":"256143447"} [..more code ..]}]}`

Why i don't get any reponse ? :/

Comment: you should remove your access token! Just did it for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function fetchData($url)
    {
        $channel = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);     //add this
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);     // and this line to support https
        $output = curl_exec($channel);
        curl_close($channel);
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the function he posted? It should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @AmalMurali i don't know what i did wrong, but now it works perfectly

Comment: @AmalMurali cURL will return bool(false) because of the https

Comment: @CSGO: Oh, right. It worked on my system for some strange reason. But you're right (+1); I didn't notice the `https`.